# What is a good way to copy data from a Tkinter screen?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, clipboard

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows. I am trying to write a data table to a Tkinter frame using labels and arranging the data as a grid.  This seems to work fine. I now want to be able to select the data in the table using a mouse and copy it to the clipboard. Is there a way to do this? Should I be using a different widget in Tkinter?

```
row=1
col=0
sep=Frame(root)

for itemcat in summary:
    Label(sep, text=str(itemcat), fg='red', bg='yellow').grid(row=row, column=col,sticky='NSEW',padx=1, pady=1)              
    row+=1
```

Comment: Would be helpful if someone tell me why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a canvas to draw the grid and then save as a postscript file. To be able to select data you will have to click in two diagonal corners or use a B2 or B3 button click to start, and release to end, and use a function to capture the coordinates of those two events.  AFAIK you have to then recreate the grid as a Tkinter PIL Image which can be saved as .png .jpg .gif or .bmp file

Comment: Thanks. However, I would like to copy it as text so that the data can be pasted onto another application such as Notepad or Excel